# How to read lucene 5.5.5 index?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, luke

What version of Luke is able to read 5.5.5 lucene's indexes? I've tried with Luke 4.10, 5.2, 5.5, 7.2 but always get this:

```
Invalid directory at the location, check console for more information. Last exception:
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path=""))): this index is too old (version: 5.5.5). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 6.0 and later.
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/luke-5.5.0 ? What message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

We also use Lucene 5.5.5 for our project.
 The latest version of Luke which supports it is 6.6.0 - https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/luke-6.6.0